# Compressibility and specific heat: interconnectedness and independence?

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter

Consider a Mott insulator (insulator arising from strong correlations). This is an incompressible phase i.e. it costs energy to add a single particle to it; the ease of compression (compressibility) may be defined as $K = \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial \mu}$, where $\rho$ is the particle density and $\mu$ is the chemical potential. For a Mott insulator, the compressibility is zero.

The Mott insulator's constant volume specific heat $C_v = T\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}$, with entropy $S$ at finite low temperatures $T$, will be exponentially suppressed due to the presence of such a particle gap. This simply indicates the absence of states close to the ground state "reachable'' by the energy provided by the low temperatures.

I was wondering if there are any phases, exotic perhaps, where (a) the specific heat is suppressed but the compressibility is large, or (b) the specific heat is large but the compressibility is diminished.